# How do I get part of website that is not written out

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How do I get part of website

[image]

I would be interested in the number shown in the picture, that is not directly displayed on the page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *data-datetime* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Python* and `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.TimeStamp span[data-interval='60']").get_attribute("data-datetime"))
  ```
- Using *Java* and `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='TimeStamp' and @data-interval='60']")).getAttribute("data-datetime"));
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` / `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Java* and `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.TimeStamp span[data-interval='60']"))).get_attribute("data-datetime"));
  ```
- Using *Python* and `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='TimeStamp' and @data-interval='60']"))).get_attribute("data-datetime"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```